# Using SOCKS5 proxy with docker build-args

Tags: docker

I am having trouble figuring out how we can use `docker build` behind a SOCKS5 proxy.

Example Dockerfile:

`FROM clearlinux:base
RUN swupd bundle-add c-basic`

Doing `docker build --build-arg="ALL_PROXY='socks5://proxy.company.com'" -t test-socks .` does not work i.e. the `RUN` command times out.

However, if I define `ENV ALL_PROXY='socks5://proxy.company.com'` within the Dockerfile, build works fine.

I've noticed that it is the case only with `ALL_PROXY` environment variable.